# Nordic Theme on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, themes

I have installed the Nordic Theme on my Ubuntu 21.04.

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1267246/

Everything looks great, but there are some issues, like for example the Ubuntu Software is showing the default theme of Gnome, and not applied to Ubuntu Software.
There are some issues like for example if I go to some apps to open some file inside is also showing the default gnome theme and not the nordic theme.

On Yaru (Ubuntu default theme) everything is ok on everything.

Does anyone knows how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

"Ubuntu Software" is a snap application, i.e., installed using the novel "snap" system rather than using the traditional APT system. These applications are sandboxed, i.e., work in their own confined environment isolated from the system. They, unfortunatelly, do not adhere to your theme settings.

Increasingly, themes are becoming available as a snap. If you install a certain theme also as a snap, then snap applications will use it.

For Nordic, you are in luck. Apparently there is an, albeit unofficial, [snap of Nordic](https://snapcraft.io/nordic-themes). Install it, and the next time you load Ubuntu Software, it should also use that theme.